# Android: How to receive callback from Content Provider when Data Changes?

Tags: android

Say I have 3 active Activities that can display and add data to a ContentProvider. What's the best way of synchronizing state among the Activities? For example, if ActivityA adds a new record to the ContentProvider, I would like ActivityB and ActivityC to receive notification so they  may update their view.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver()` method from each activity, and supply appropriate URI(s).

You can pass the base Content URI for the provider, and pass `true` for `notifyForDescendents` parameter, and your callback will get hit every time there's a change.

The Content Provider you are accessing must support this (most do).  If you are writing your own, you must call `ContentResolver.notifyChange()` with the URI of modified row(s).